# recover cakePHP model database

Tags: database, cakephp, database-schema

I have accidentally deleted whole database from my system which includes database schema of some cakePHP projects.
Rest of the codes of cakePHP project is safe. Is there a way to recover all schema from model.

I don't care of data in database because they were just dummy data but want to recover whole schema back.

Comment: What OS ? No Backup ? Which DBMS ?

Comment: Ubuntu OS. No Backup. MySql DBMS

Comment: How did you deleted the databe ? rm ?

Comment: No. Formatted my Ubuntu OS and forget to backup database

Comment: In my opinion you have very little chance to recover your database. Your best option would be trying TestDisk which gives pretty good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming cache is enabled using the default php file cache handler,

You kind of can through the model cache. It will give you the table name and the columns plus datatype. the format isn't the easiest to read either and would take a bit of time to extract the information about the table from each file.
Also im assuming you are using PHP file sessions and cache?

have a look in:

```
/tmp/cache/models
```

Should find some serialized data that contains information about your model/table schemas. Might be easier to read using a json formatter like:

> https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Should make it slightly easier to read.

You will still need to manually write out your `CREATE TABLE` queries. this will just give you information about the columns from the tables.